# How to put a time limit on user input?

Tags: c++, user-input

I have tried various setups with input and my one second timer but nothing is working. The entire code is brought to a halt when it reaches the part asking for input. I have an unbuffered stream, so I don't need to press enter to send the input. Also the purpose of this is for a pac-man game I'm designing for terminal use. What I want is basically to have a one second interval where the user can enter a command. If no command is entered, I want the pac-man to continue moving the direction it was moving the last time a command was entered.

EDIT:

```
time_t startTime, curTime;

    time(&startTime);
    do
    {
        input=getchar();
        time(&curTime);
    } while((curTime - startTime) < 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gut feeling tells me this:

- Have one thread dedicated to processing user input and putting key events into a queue
- The timer-activated thread, on every activation, consumes all key events in the queue, using the one that happened last, at the point of thread activation.

Make sure your access to the queue is synchronized.

```
// I/O Thread:
while (!stop) {
    input = getchar();
    lock_queue();
    queue.push_back(input);
    unlock_queue();
}

// Timer Thread:
while (!stop) {
    lock_queue();
    if (queue.size() == 0) {
        action = DEFAULT_ACTION;
    } else {
        // either handle multiple key events somehow
        // or use the last key event:
        action = queue.back();
        queue.clear();
    }
    unlock_queue();
    perform_action(action);
    sleep();
}
```

Full example posted as a [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/1982902).

Comment: First result for "posix threads" search on google: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/. I wouldn't know better myself, but *posix threads* is what you want.

Comment: Is this code good as is? It doesn't seem like these `while` loops would run at the same time.

Comment: It's *definitely* not good as is :-) The comments imply that you write the `pthreads` machinery for running them in two separate threads. But it's easy. The link I provided has this example later on in the text: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/samples/hello.c

Comment: Ok. That's what I thought. Up until today I'd never even heard of threads. Comes with being new to programming I guess. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In that case I would suggest reading a book on multithreaded programming. There are incredibly many pitfalls when writing multithreaded code, one could grow old and not understand all of them. Your example seems simple enough though, don't feel discouraged by this statement.

Comment: Added a working example as a [Github Gist link](https://gist.github.com/1982902). Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `alarm()` (or similar timer function) to throw and have your application catch a `SIGALRM`, though this is definitely overkill for PacMac.  Consider using a separate thread (POSIX thread) to control a timer.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix, you can simply use select or poll with a timeout on the standard input file descriptor (STDIN_FILENO, or fileno(stdin)). I would not bring in mouse traps built of signals and threads just for this.

Comment: +1. Creating a separate thread for everything is some sort of Java disease... Those people are severely misguided.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a non-blocking input function such as getch() but it isn't very cross platform compatible.

Ideally you should be using events to update the game state, depending on which OS you are targeting you could use the OS events for key press or maybe a library such as SDL.